# SQL запрос на поиск из строки

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Есть строковая переменная под названием `"object"` она хранит в себе строку состоящую из двух других полей `"name"` и `"model"`, например `"object"` =  `"Смартфон Honor 10 KDJ-103 DUA"` - где `"Смартфон Honor 10"` это `"name"`, а `KDJ-103 DUA` это `"model"`. Я должен с помощью `"object"` найти совпадение в бд.

Каким запросом можно найти совпадения, предполагаю что нужно как-то так, но пишу с ошибками:   `LIKE  '%"model"%'`  ?

```html
SELECT id, model, name, image
FROM  `catalog_tovar` 
WHERE  'Смартфон Honor 10 KDJ-103 DUA' LIKE  '%"model"%'
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `concat('%', model, '%')`

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, работает, можете добавить для отметки ответа.